# can we check a file's read write permission before opening it in kernel

Tags: c, linux, file, permissions, kernel

I want to open a file in read only mode in kernel but before i do that i want to check if the file has permission to read, how can i check it? Because to even check that i would need a file pointer pointing to the input file.

```
filp_open(args->inputfile, O_RDONLY, 0);
```

Is there any way to check it before opening it? I tried using, but it always fails

```
if (!fileptr->f_op->read)
{
     error = -EACCES;
     printk("reading input file failed\n");
}
```

Comment: The problem is there's a race condition between checking permissions and opening where said permissions can be changed by something else. Just try to open it and handle failures appropriately.

Comment: It is interesting how an **user-space** code in the *accepted* answer can be suitable for a **kernel-space** code...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `access(char *filepath,int mode)` that checks file access rights.

`mode`describes what you want to check: F_OK (existence), or an OR combination of R_OK(read), W_OK(write) or X_OK(execute).

So for your problem, you could use:

```
#include <unistd.h>
...

if( access( filename, R_OK ) != -1 ) {
    // can read file
} else {
    // cannot read file
}
```